# XMLHttpRequest working on Chrome+Edge, but not Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, firefox

I'm trying to add a progress bar to my upload form. So far it works in Chrome and Edge, but firefox does not.

I've tried checking the console in Firefox to see if it's throwing any errors but it's not. I've discovered its not even attempting to run the function progressHandler(event). In Chrome it is. Can you guys please help me figure out what's going on? Thanks

```
function _(el) {
  return document.getElementById(el);
}

function progressHandler(event) {
  var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
  _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
}

function uploadFile() {
  var file = _("hid").files[0];
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("hid", file);
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
  ajax.open("POST", "upload.php");
  ajax.send(formdata);
}
```

Comment: For the record, this is what I used to get to this point. I just trimmed the fat. I don't need it to give me any details on errors, I have php doing that for me.

https://codepen.io/jlembert/pen/WQBgxy

Comment: Huh, very interesting. If I add an alert after ajax.send(formdata), it works ONLY when the alert is displayed. If I press okay, the progress bar stops. Weird...

Comment: Your Codepen works fine for me in Firefox

Comment: Yea, it does for me too. That codepen isn't something I wrote by the way. I just found it while looking for how to do this. The crazy thing is, it doesn't work on my own site. I've tried everything I could possibly think of. Now I'm seeing that if I put an alert after ajax.send(formdata); it will actually work. At least until I close the alert box and then it stops dead in its tracks.

Comment: https://theromdepot.com/upload.php. Heres the link to the actual site I'm trying to get it to work on. The console shows no errors for me.

Comment: You appear to have HTML comments in your JS

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Are you talking about in what I posted? Because I don't have any comments in there at all.

Comment: Sure... you have for example `<!--Get File Name-->` and `<!--Get Title-->` in your second `<script>` block. If you want to use comments in your scripts, I suggest you use `// Get File Name` and `// Get Title`

Comment: Oh, I see. You were talking about a different part of the script. I fixed that, but I still don't have a solution to my current problem. Why do you think adding an alert at the end makes it work and when I close out of the alert it breaks again. That's the weirdest part to me.